# Spresense sdk spi4をmyappから利用するには

Tags: spresense

Spresense sdk v1.5.0(VS code)を使っています

app追加で、myappを作成しました

myapp_main()の中から、spi4を使いたいです

イメージは下記ですが、インクルードも通らないし
使い方が、全くわかりません

```c
\#include "cxd56_spi.h"

spi_dev_s * spi4;

int myapp_main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  printf("myapp spi test\n");

  spi4 = cxd56_spibus_initialize(4);

  printf("freq %d\n",  spi4->frequency);

  return 0;
}
```

加えて、読み書きを同時に、例えば、4byte実行したいのですが、
読み書き一発の関数もわかりません
最初は、loopbackイメージ

Arduino IDEだと直線的アプローチでできるのですが、

nuttxのドライバへ登録見たいな感じになるのでしょうか？

ps. サンプルコードにあればよかったのですが、見当たらず

---

将来的にはDMAを使いたいです

```
■SDKコンフィグ
*CXD56xx Configuration
SPI*
> ✔︎ CXD56_SPI

*CXD56xx Configuration ➤ SPI
SPI4*

> ✔︎ CXD56_SPI4

*CXD56xx Configuration ➤ SPI ➤ SPI4
DMAC support for SPI4 TX*
> ✔︎ CXD56_DMAC_SPI4_TX

*CXD56xx Configuration ➤ SPI ➤ SPI4
DMAC support for SPI4 RX*
> ✔︎ CXD56_DMAC_SPI4_RX
```

Answer (score 1):

SpresenseのSPIを使っているLCDのドライバの実装を見ると、
spresense/nuttx/include/nuttx/spi/spi.hに定義されているマクロを使って操作するようです。
なので、インクルードするファイルは2つで、

```
#include <nuttx/spi/spi.h>
#include <cxd56_spi.h>
```

で行けると思います。

初期化処理ですが、
DMAを使う場合は、別にDMAの設定が必要なようです。

sdk/bsp/board/common/src/cxd56_ili9340.c:347行目付近から抜粋

```
      spi = cxd56_spibus_initialize(DISPLAY_SPI);
      hdl = cxd56_dmachannel(DISPLAY_DMA_TXCH, DISPLAY_DMA_TX_MAXSIZE);
      if (hdl)
        {
          conf.channel_cfg = DISPLAY_DMA_TXCH_CFG;
          conf.dest_width  = CXD56_DMAC_WIDTH8;
          conf.src_width   = CXD56_DMAC_WIDTH8;
          cxd56_spi_dmaconfig(DISPLAY_SPI, CXD56_SPI_DMAC_CHTYPE_TX, hdl, &conf);
        }
      hdl = cxd56_dmachannel(DISPLAY_DMA_RXCH, DISPLAY_DMA_RX_MAXSIZE);
      if (hdl)
        {
          conf.channel_cfg = DISPLAY_DMA_RXCH_CFG;
          conf.dest_width  = CXD56_DMAC_WIDTH8;
          conf.src_width   = CXD56_DMAC_WIDTH8;
          cxd56_spi_dmaconfig(DISPLAY_SPI, CXD56_SPI_DMAC_CHTYPE_RX, hdl, &conf);
        }
```

SPIのモードなどの設定は、nuttx/spi/spi.hに定義されているマクロを使っているようです。

```
      SPI_SETMODE(priv->spi, SPIDEV_MODE3);
      SPI_SETBITS(priv->spi, 8);
      SPI_HWFEATURES(priv->spi, 0);
      SPI_SETFREQUENCY(priv->spi, ILI9340_SPI_MAXFREQUENCY);
```

あとは、送受信を同時に行うには、SPI_EXCHANGE()というマクロを使えば良いようです。

使い方はnuttxのヘッダに記載があります。
nuttx/include/nuttx/spi/spi.h:377行目から

```
/****************************************************************************
 * Name: SPI_EXCHANGE
 *
 * Description:
 *   Exahange a block of data from SPI. Required.
 *
 * Input Parameters:
 *   dev      - Device-specific state data
 *   txbuffer - A pointer to the buffer of data to be sent
 *   rxbuffer - A pointer to the buffer in which to receive data
 *   nwords   - the length of data that to be exchanged in units of words.
 *              The wordsize is determined by the number of bits-per-word
 *              selected for the SPI interface.  If nbits <= 8, the data is
 *              packed into uint8_t's; if nbits >8, the data is packed into
 *              uint16_t's
 *
 * Returned Value:
 *   None
 *
 ****************************************************************************/
```

最後に、cxd56_spi.hがインクルードエラーになるのは、
デフォルトでインクルードパスが通っていないためのようで、それを通すには、
myappのディレクトリの.vscode/application.mkの中の71行目辺りに、
CFLAGSとCXXFLAGSの定義があるので、
その後ろの行に、

```
CFLAGS += -I $(SDKTOP)/bsp/src
CXXFLAGS += -I $(SDKTOP)/bsp/src
```

を加えてパスを追加すれば良いと思います。

参考になれば幸いです。